# Part identification - SMD transistor or MOSFET

Tags: identification

I’m trying to identify the following small... probably MOSFET? The ‘X73A’ marking doesn’t help me find anything. It’s in a controller recharging circuit and gates on a signal from the controller, I believe by allowing power to flow when a controller is present and not fully charged.

[image]

Comment: It could be a PMOS. The Source and gate are tied together with a 100k resistor. The gate may be pulled down to allow current to flow, like you said. F2 is a fuse in series with the source, which supports the idea of Q6 being a pass transistor with the voltage source on the other side of F2. Hard to tell the current rating, but I have used PMOS in SOT-23 packages (as the one shown), and they can switch up to 3.2A, but I have never push that much through  a SOT-23

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I’ll look into that. The fuse is 1A, so it would definitely not hit 3.2 even if it were rated for it.

Comment: What an amazing camera you have that makes a PCB look like a Monet.

Comment: @Andyaka just a really good phone app, Camera+. The iPhone camera is decent, but the app takes photos in RAW so you can crop in close and still have decent detail.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an [AO3407A](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3407.pdf) 4.1A 30V P-channel MOSFET.

From the position it might be to protect against reverse battery input.